# Traverse a query result into a while loop

Tags: cakephp, orm, iterator, resultset, cakephp-3.x

I'd like to traverse a resultset using a **while()** loop instead the most common **foreach()**

If I have this code for example:

```
$articles = $this->Articles->find();
foreach ($articles as $article) {
   echo $article->name;
}
```

How can I access rows of $articles using a while loop ?

I already tried traverse it using **next()** or **$articles->next()** with no success.

Comment: Why would you want to do that anyways?

Comment: I need to perform a control-break logic (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_break) old fashioned ? :)

Comment: I see, but shouldn't that be possible with a `foreach` loop too? In any case, if applicable I'd probably suggest to use the result sets grouping functionality.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I am trying the grouped approach also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure that you really need to use a `while()` loop for what you're trying to achieve, but to answer the question, you have to first get the result set, and then use its [**`Iterator::valid()`**](http://php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php) implementation for the loop condition, this is where the current result is being fetched, which you can then access via `current()`. Advancing the cursor is then being done using `next()`.

```
$query = $this->Articles->find();
$resultSet = $query->all();

while ($resultSet->valid()) {
    $article = $resultSet->current();
    // ...
    $resultSet->next();
}
```

See also **[API > \Cake\ORM\ResultSet](https://api.cakephp.org/3.4/class-Cake.ORM.ResultSet.html)**